# Check if jquery method is loaded from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dependant methods in jquery. I would like to test dynamicaly if they exists.
I tired this simple way:

```
console.log(jQuery.isFunction($.fn.popover));
```

which returned true. But when I put method name into variable I received a false.

```
var func = '$.fn.popover';
console.log(jQuery.isFunction(window[func]));
```

Does anybody know how can I test if method exists from variable. Thanks

Comment: First thing to check: what does `$.fn.popover === window['$.fn.popover']` return, just out of curiosity?

Comment: as I expected return false but when I try `var func = 'jQuery';
console.log(jQuery.isFunction(window[func]));` I receive true. Even with `var func = '$'`;

Comment: You can try this way: var func = $.fn.popover;

Comment: That ^ won't work because you assign _the function_, which you need to know already exists, to the variable. Presumably OP wants to check for feature support using the string name of the function.

Comment: Thanks it worked as in linked thread. Problem with that thread was that it is not easy to find it. So I recommend this question to leave it here to others find also answer.

Comment: @msanford I am not assigning function itself, I am assigning only function name as text with quotas.

Comment: You can try if it work for you: var func = $.fn.popover; console.log(jQuery.isFunction(window.func))

Comment: @BjørsonÅlmer I know, that's what I was saying to Hanif: you want to do something fundamentally different than his suggestion allows. That's why I hinted at testing equality beforehand. The linked question marked as duplicate will help :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your clarification @msanford. Your contribute was helpfull :-)

Comment: If `jQuery.noConflict()`is used then `window.$` will not be `jQuery`. Is heavily used in wordpess for example. Might be better to string replace `'$'` with `'jQuery'`